# Whats wrong with this C Function?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct Carta* BAR_tppCarta
BAR_tppCarta * BAR_CriarBaralho () 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k=0;
    BAR_tppCarta *baralho;
    baralho = (BAR_tppCarta *) malloc(NUM_CARTAS*sizeof(BAR_tppCarta));
    if(!baralho)
        return NULL;
    for(i=COPAS;i<=ESPADA;i++)
        for(j=AS;j<=KING;j++)
            {
                baralho[k]->naipe = i;
                baralho[k]->valor = j;
                k++;
            }
    return baralho;
}
```

when I call this function in another module, using

```
 BAR_tppCarta *baralho = BAR_CriarBaralho();
```

The windows stop working, like a debug error. 
Can anyone help me please?

Very thanks!
Alessandro

Comment: COPAS, ESPADAS, AS, KING AND NUM_CARTAS is constants defined in a table .inc

COPAS = 14 ; ESPADAS = 17 ; AS = 0 ; KING = 13 ; NUM_CARTAS = 52

Comment: Please use the edit function for addendums to your questions (or answers)?

Comment: I think AS must be 1. Else you have an overflow in your loops since (0..14) is actually 15 repetitions.

Answer (score 7):

`BAR_tppCarta` is just a pointer, so all you are returning is an array of uninitialised pointers (and you are also stomping over memory). I suspect that this line:

```
typedef struct Carta* BAR_tppCarta;
```

should probably be:

```
typedef struct Carta BAR_tppCarta;
```

and these two lines:

```
            baralho[k]->naipe = i;
            baralho[k]->valor = j;
```

should be:

```
            baralho[k].naipe = i;
            baralho[k].valor = j;
```

---

Alternatively you can keep the original definition of `BAR_tppCarta` as

```
typedef struct Carta* BAR_tppCarta;
```

and then allocate memory for each instance:

```
for(i=COPAS;i<=ESPADA;i++)
    for(j=AS;j<=KING;j++)
        {
            baralho[k] = malloc(sizeof(struct Carta));
            baralho[k]->naipe = i;
            baralho[k]->valor = j;
            k++;
        }
```

although I would advise against this on the grounds of complexity unless you have a good reason to do it this way.

Comment: Sure - you can do that too, but then you will need to allocate memory for each instance. See updated answer above.

Comment: hmmmm thats the point! I didnt allocate memory for each of them... this is the problem.. I will try that now